# Java add characters as octet to existing byte array?

Tags: java, byte, arrays

Essentially i have

```
byte[] arr = new byte[500];
int cnt = 0;
String[] str = {'aaa','bbb','ccc');
for (String label : str){
   arr[cnt++] = label.subString(0,1).getBytes();
}
```

The end goal is the have arr[0] be 'a' as a byte, arr[1] 'a' as a byte etc. I'd debug but i'm having issues and was hoping for some clarification. I know getBytes() returns a byteArray, but since it is the result will only ever be 1 byte (since it is a single character) can i do what i did or is this resulting in an array nested array like

```
arr = {[aAsByte],[aAsByte]...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have a second `for` loop that loops around each character of the `String` and casts it to a `byte`. Do note that the cast from a `char` to a `byte` can result in loss of information, but it won't happen if your characters are only lowercase alphabetical.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] arr = new byte[500];
    int cnt = 0;
    String[] str = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"};
    for (String label : str){
        for (char c : label.toCharArray()) {
            arr[cnt++] = (byte) c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Its always so simple after the fact. Need more coffee i guess